# viewing of paperclip attachment not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have uploaded a file images.jpeg using the code
`<%= s.file_field :job_offer %>` . uploading was fine but when tries to view the uploaded file using code `link_to "View" , @job.job_offer.url`, it throws error. There is nothing in log files. Also all other places which have same kind of code works fine.

When I checked network errors, it shows `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. in response header , type is `Content-Type:text/html`. if this would be the problem, how to fix this?

I've tried giving type = 'image/jpeg' in link, but still the same. is there any other way to give type ?

model.rb

```
  has_attached_file :job_offer,
                :url => "/uploads/:class/:id/:attachment/:attachment_fullname?:timestamp",
                :path => "uploads/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

and in schema,

```
t.string   "job_offer_file_name"
t.string   "job_offer_content_type"
t.integer  "job_offer_file_size"
```

Answer (score 0):

for displaying image you need to use image tag below is the syntax:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
    <%= image_tag "image_path", class: "some css class here" %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to( image_tag(@job.job_offer.url), jobs_path, :class=>"abc") %>
```

Comment: but it wont be always images. any type of files can be uploaded